# How do I install Eclipse?

Tags: macbook-pro

I just downloaded the .tar ball and unzipped it. It seems to run as a standalone from the folder that was unzipped in my Downloads folder. However, I want to install this so it is in applications, but there are so many other files like configurations. Where do I put those? I tried dragging just the eclipse.app to the applications folder and when i try to run it, it says the shared dependencies are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Eclipse is not a well behaved app. Yo need the Eclipse.app and the other files in the downloaded directory to keep the same relative directory structure. Thus you need to move the whole directory from Downloads as is. I moved it to ~/eclipse.helios and then dragged the Eclipse.app into the Dock.

Answer (score 3):

The main Eclipse application needs to be kept in the same folder as its support files otherwise it won't start. What I have done is to keep Eclipse in its own folder, somewhere out of the way, then right-click on the main Eclipse application and select "Make Alias". This will create a file called `Eclipse alias`. You can then move the alias to wherever you want it to be, without worrying about the rest of the Eclipse files. You can move this alias to the Applications folder, and then rename it back to `Eclipse`.

Comment: Where did you store folder with its support files?

Comment: @Doug I put the Eclipse folder in my home folder.